# How to create a search form with multiple search fields

Tags: search, advanced-custom-fields

I have a client that would like to add a search facility to their site but...

They would like to allow the user to search various different custom fields.

Here's an example of the sort of thing I'm talking about... http://psychcrime.org/database/

The site will be using Advanced Custom Fields.

I'm amazed this is proving so tricky using Wordpress. I'm aware there are lots of search plugins but most seem to still only work with one search field, or just give extra fields for tags, dates or categories.

What I'm looking for is a search form with a search field for each custom field so for example, one search field for ID number, one for name and so on.

I also build sites using ExpressionEngine and this would be so easy using EE I'm puzzled why it's so tricky using Wordpress. The trouble is the rest of the client's site is on Wordpress so I'm trying to avoid rebuilding the whole site on EE.

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: check this website https://www.dianova.com/produkt-kategorie/weltweite-produkte/, is this search form good for you?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I gave an example of the sort of search form in my original question. Is the form example you gave one that you built?